# Pyephem: 'Titan' object has no attribute 'mag'

Tags: python, pyephem

I tried to determine the magnitude of Titan, but the result is this error message: 
AttributeError: 'Titan' object has no attribute 'mag'

```
>>> import ephem
>>> t = ephem.Titan()
>>> t.compute()
>>> t.ra
15:55:10.52
>>> t.mag
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Titan' object has no attribute 'mag'
```

Doesn't Titan have the attribute magnitude? Why? I can determine the magnitude for Uranus, or the Moon, but not for Titan. At least not with the 'mag' attribute.
What would be the way?

edit:
With versions 3.7.5.3 and 3.7.5.1 of ephem.

Comment: As far as I can see, Titan should have a magnitude. Reference: https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/pyephem/blob/master/libastro-3.7.6/satmoon.c

Answer (score 4):

According to the [PyEphem Homepage Docs](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/quick.html#bodies)

The `ephem.Body` type is the only type with a `.mag` attribute

Titan is classified as a `ephem.PlanetMoon` object and so does not have a `.mag` attribute

The current list of `ephem.Body` objects are:
Jupiter,Mars,Mercury,Moon,Neptune,Pluto,Saturn,Sun,Uranus,Venus.

I am not aware of any way in ephem to calculate the `.mag` of an `ephem.PlanetMoon` object

Comment: Thanks. I will try to calculate Titan's magnitude depending on Saturn's magnitude. I hoped to obtain it directly but apparently it is not possible...

Thanks anyway!